# AzurePowershell Get-AzureSubscription one subscription is missing

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I made a system that every morning, I get CSV files using AzurePopwershell from Azure

for example

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Kazu Pay-As-You-Go"  
Get-AzureVM | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\kazu\Desktop\AzureProject\kazu-Pay-As-You-Go-VM.csv"-NoTypeInformation
```

This morning, My boss just told me That our company only getting information of two of directories/accounts from Azure. My company has three directories/accounts. so, we clicked on "Subscriptions" on left top on  https://manage.windowsazure.com/--->"FILTER BY DIRECTORY:", There are 3 directories/account,  he told me we are getting information from directories/account from only "mycompany3" and "mycompany1" , he also wants me to get information from "mycompany2".

so I clicked "directory3" and it shows under "FILTER BY SUBSCRIPTIONS:"

- Select ALL
- 3-month Free trial
- kazu Pay-As-You-Go

I clicked "directory1" and it shows under "FILTER BY SUBSCRIPTIONS:"

- Select ALL
- Pay-As-You-Go

I clicked "directory2" and it shows under "FILTER BY SUBSCRIPTIONS:"

- Select ALL
- Main Subscription

SO I went AzurePowershell and did

```
Get-AzureSubscription
```

echo was

- 3-month Free trial
- Pay-As-You-Go
- kazu Pay-As-You-Go

I noticed that "Main Subscription" is missing

At first, when I started to do project, I followed http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2013/11/06/set-by-step-manage-windows-azure-using-powershell.aspx

How can I connect to "directory2" , "Main Subcription"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you authenticate with Azure Powershell? By using Add-AzureAccount, or by using Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile? If you used the publish settings file, you might not have had the other subscription in there. Try using Add-AzureAccount, which should mimic the same permission set as when you are logged in.

Comment: Thanks for response I did Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile

Comment: So I would either export a new PublishSettings file and make sure you can see the relevant subscription in there, or try Add-AzureAccount.

Comment: so I added a user which access to all Azure account for my companies, I still do not see "Main Subscription". Do I have to delete Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile? If so, How can I delete it?

Comment: So you ran the command Add-AzureAccount, and logged in with the same credentials that you used to login to the portal, where you see the subscription? You should not have to run Remove-AzureAccount/Remove-AzureSubscription, but you can in order to "reset" things if you would like.

Remove-AzureAccount - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722529.aspx
Remove-AzureSubscription - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495109.aspx

Comment: interesting thing is this comes up "WARNING: There is no subscription associated with account myemail@myemail.net."

Comment: He has access to all azure account for my my company.

Comment: $securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -string "password" -AsPlainText -Force 

$cred = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $securepassword)

Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred

Comment: You can just run Add-AzureAccount (without any parameters), and it will prompt you for credentials

Comment: Good New, It started to show up, but Is this expire 12 hours or I do not need to do anymore "Add-azureaccount"

Comment: In my experience, this authorization will persist until you explicitly remove the subscription, and I haven't found any documentation to say when it would expire. It still probably wouldn't be the best idea to use this method on a server.